# Modifying return value of getters of String fields

Tags: grails, groovy

Let's say I have classes similar to domain classes in my application with some Long, Double, Date and String fields. These classes extend base class with some common fields and few common methods. Whenever I access class field (though getter) that is String, I want to make some changes to the value returned (for example remove html tags). Is there a better way than making implementations of getters for each fields of String type? What about inherited fields?

Answer (score 1):

Don't change default getter/setter implementations created for you by Grails. You would definitely mess up your application in various places. Grails uses convention over configuration so getters/setters should definitely remain unchanged.

Create your own methods that return what you want: for a field title create method getStrippedTitle(). You can add this method to transients too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very similar to one Burt Beckwith provided so my comment made there would apply here too.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the value that's set, or return a value that's different from what was set, you'll confuse Hibernate. That's because when you load an instance from the database, Hibernate keeps the original data in its 1st-level cache, and returns a domain object instance to you. When you flush, it compares the current state with the original, and if it changed, it will push the changes to the database. So if you return a different value than what was set, but don't really change the value, Hibernate can't tell the difference.

You're much better off leaving the properties alone and creating methods that return altered data. One convention I've used is that if for example you have a `String body` field, you can access it via the property name `body` or the getter `getBody()`, but you can create a `body()` method that's unknown to Hibernate and returns whatever you want.

Comment: I agree with your warning. But I am not talking here about actual domain classes mapped to database. What I use possibly can be named transfer objects (very specific situation solved using SomeJson classes to form jsons to client and get the data from the client). And implementing getter or similar in function methods for each field in each such class is what I am trying to avoid. Tried some meta-programming stuff with no success as it is very new to me...